# Problems with touchpad scrolling JS

Tags: javascript, html

When i scroll on touchpad with two finger on website it triggers scrolling inertially for 1s-1.5s.
So when i console.log('scroll') it , i see 'scroll' 68 times.
And because of that my programm triggers scroll event multiple times after some delay.
For example i scrolled on touchpad, it got event, and after 1.5s it still triggers scroll.
Question is that, how to make scroll event on touchpad not inertiall, or maybe limit scroll count?

```
 document.addEventListener("wheel", this.wheelFilter, {passive: false});
    wheelFilter = e => {
    this.updateWheelPrevTime();
    this.preventParentScroll();

    if (
        this._wheelTimeDiff > this._REAL_SCROLL_TIME
    ) {
        this.onMouseWheel(e);
    } else {
        this.updateWheelFireTime();
    }
}
```

Tried to debounce, doesnt work
Tried to unsubscribe event and then suscribe, it gets prev scroll again

Comment: Debouncing works for this, your implementation probably has flaws. Please post code. Otherwise we can only speculate what the issue is.

Comment: @PeterSmith upd